# Texi2dvi Command Not Found on Fedora

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to compile a package named `daikon` on fedora18 but when I'm compiling its documents it returns error because of `texi2dvi command`! even `texinfo` package and `texlive` package both are installed and latest version.

```
 make[1]: texi2dvi: Command not found
```

Comment: Does `which texi2dvi` show anything?

Comment: @Benjamin Bannier:it shows /usr/bin/which: no texi2dvi in (***)

Comment: @Mjina: Looks like you need to install texinfo-tex, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=209957.

Comment: @ Matthias:returns nothing.

Comment: @Benjamin Bannier:thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 8):

you need to install `texinfo-tex` package.
on fedora `yum install texinfo-tex`